# Is it possible to add offset value to universal time in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone, utc

I have a scheduling application which is hosted on godaddy's server and is being used in Arizona. The problem I am having is an issue with the timezone. The server's timezone is different than that of the users. I want to do it in a database, as i can get universal time by `select GETUTCDATE()`. Now I want to convert it for Arizona's timezone, as some of the places in Arizona supports daylight saving and some doesn't support. So can someone let me know how can solve this?

Comment: I agree - downvotes here without any explanation are unfair.

Comment: It's tricker than you think, guys. It turns out that a small portion of Arizona is under daylight savings each year, although the majority of the state doesn't use DST.

Comment: Yes i know that's the major prob otherwise we can just minus 7 hours from the universal time.

Comment: @R.S.Rana - I added that comment so that others trying to solve the problem would be aware of it, since you didn't mention it in your original question (or mention anything you tried at all, for that matter, which could explain the downvotes).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should try to create computed column.

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table>
   ADD <your_column> AS (
      DATEADD(
         /*FOR EXAMPLE*/ HOUR, 
         /*OFFSET*/      -5, 
         /*BASE_DATE*/   sysdatetime()) 
      )
```

Ofcorse for Offset You can specify value dependent from other column, like:

```
 ALTER TABLE <your_table>
   ADD <your_column> AS (
      DATEADD(
         /*FOR EXAMPLE*/ HOUR, 
         /*OFFSET*/      -<date_offset_column>, 
         /*BASE_DATE*/   sysdatetime()) 
      )
```